# Linear combination problem from linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Express the column matrix $b$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$. (Use $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$ respectively for the columns of A.)
>
> $$\begin{align}
> A&=\begin{pmatrix}-2 &-5 &4\\3 &-3&5\end{pmatrix}\\b&=\begin{pmatrix}11\\28\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$

Comment: (-1) "This question does not show any research effort."

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
A&=\begin{pmatrix}-2 &-5 &4\\3 &-3&5\end{pmatrix}\\b&=\begin{pmatrix}11\\28\end{pmatrix}\\
Ax&=b\\
\begin{pmatrix}-2 &-5 &4\\3 &-3&5\end{pmatrix}x&=\begin{pmatrix}11\\28\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}-2 &-5 &4\\0 &-10.5&11\end{pmatrix}x&=\begin{pmatrix}11\\44.5\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}-2 &0 &1.2381\\0 &-10.5&11\end{pmatrix}x&=\begin{pmatrix}-10.1905\\44.5\end{pmatrix}\\
x&=(a\quad b\quad c)^T\\
\text{Let, }b&=0\\
\therefore c&=4.0455\\
\therefore a&=2.5909\\
\blacksquare
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, actually the answer is supposed to come out in the format similar to: b = -A1 - 3A2 + A3

Comment: @user2153126. There can be multiple answers.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm looking for the general form - similar to what I indicated: b = ___________

Comment: @user2153126, if you are suggesting that [-1 -3 1] is an answer then it's wrong. You can verify this yourself by multiplying. Also, to get an answer in a different form, simply replace the $b=0$ step with your choice of pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to formulate and to solve the respective system of linear equations.

Comment: yeah, I understand the concept but I can't get the correct answer

Comment: I don't see how one could understand this concept and not be able to get the answer.